# Timesheet Entries UX

Tags: information-architecture, input, status

**How to distinguish new time entries**

I have a timesheet that looks like this:
[image: Timesheet]

Which works well. the customers can see all their time entries on one screen and works well reading the times across the week at a glance.

However the issue comes when a user has to enter their timesheets and can be working on up to 5 different assignments, that need to be added via the 'Add in time' drop down.

User story:

As a user i fill out my timesheet at the end of the week, and it totals to 34.5 hours

Then 2 days later i need to go back in the add additional time for another assignment that i worked on which i forgot about. So the weeks total hours is now 42 hours.

34.5 hours - Assignment 1

7.5 hours - Assigment 2

However i do not know which project the total time has been allocated to.

---

What is the best way to distinguish this new information that has been added

- New time added from different assignments
- How to tell at a glance which time has been allocated to what assignment

Hope this is clear..

Comment: This topic is related (not the same issue) to this https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/127897/best-way-to-determine-today-and-tomorrow-in-a-slider/127905#127905

Comment: Not totally related, but the language `add in time` reads oddly to me. What does this represent? Add something `in time`? Adding `in time` (like my arrival)? Alternative such as `Add time` make no literal sense. Should it not be something like `add timesheet entry/booking?` maybe this is a known taxonomy to others but to me it seems weird

Comment: Can the user have 5 or 20 assignments ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something similar to the image below. A drop down with the ability to select all of the assignments or individual assignments. The drop down can have the totals of the hours listed by the name to allow a quick total hours. Selecting one assignment would provide more details for the week days and total by only showing the times for the assignment you have selected.

[image: Dropdown with assignment selections and a description of the total hours visible as well]

While this does not provide a quick view of all times of all projects for all days of the week at once, it is very mobile friendly and easily understood.

Answer (score 0):

Hey interesting problem.

How much freedom do you have? Can you expand the functionality of the form or are you limited to purely UI fixes?

One approach I have encountered (although on Desktop) is where the entries are divided by category. See attached picture:

[image]

This approach will add some complexity but I don't see many other ways to add what you are asking for without expanding the functionality of the feature.

Hope this gives you some perspective!